# Config Zotero Server

Tags: php

I want run Zotero Data Server according to [this documentation](https://github.com/Panzerkampfwagen/dataserver/blob/master/misc/Zotero_Data_Server_Installation_Debian.pdf)

In Setting Up Zotero Data Server step, i run `$ sudo ./test_reset` command and it give me `Reset is successfull. Now run ./test_setup`

when i run this command `$ sudo ./test_setup` it shows this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Z_CONFIG' not found in /srv/http/ZoteroDataServer/include/header.inc.php on line 91
```

And this id my `server php -v`

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 06:56:34)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

what can i do to solve problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify config/config.inc.php and change the first line from `<?` to `<?php` ... then you need to modify dpconnect.inc.php and set the password for mysql correctly, do "service memcached restart" to ensure that memcached is running, and then test_setup should work properly. This is what I had to do in RHEL6 ...

Comment: And this is why I love stackoverflow... thanks @Doug.